# Docker-compose : php:7.0-apache , enable mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, docker

I want to develop my php app with docker-compose.
Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: app_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  web:
    image: php:7.0-apache
    container_name: app_web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
    - ./yii2/web/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

The app is running with .htaccess. So, I need to enable mod_rewrite.
How to enable this apache configuration ?

```
 Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: You should use the Docker file for web image.

Comment: Entrypoint to your problem: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/. Search on the page for "Changing DocumentRoot (or other Apache configuration)". Note that using apache as a separate service to talk to a `-fpm` version of php might be easier if you have other configuration to take into account.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding

```
command: >
  bash -c "a2enmod rewrite
  && apache2-foreground"
```

Like so:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: app_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  web:
    image: php:7.0-apache
    command: >
      bash -c "a2enmod rewrite
      && apache2-foreground"
    container_name: app_web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./yii2/web/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).